# line breaks and blank lines ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read some text from a txt file with following code:

```
  using (StreamReader sr = 
                 File.OpenText(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("OrderEmailBody.txt")))
  {
      String input;
      while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
          emailBody += input;
      }
}
```

The txt file has some blank lines and line breaks but this code is ignoring all line breaks and blank lines in txt file. Please suggest how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't ignore them, you just don't add them to your mail body.

```
emailBody += input + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  using (StreamReader sr = 
             File.OpenText(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("OrderEmailBody.txt")))
  {
      String input;
      while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
          emailBody += input;
          email += Environment.NewLine;
      }
  }
```